# Creating Jira issue with REST API

Tags: python, jira-rest-api, python-jira

Having issues with trying to create an issue with Jira through the APIs, below is a sample of my code. We are using enterprise jira, I have to replace certain sections with  so I hope it wont effect your ability to provide help.

```
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import requests

user = '<ID>'
password = '<password>'
url = 'https://<enterprise>jira.<domain>.com/projects/<MYKEY>/rest/api/3/issue'


headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

json_data = {
    
  "fields": {
    "project": {
      "key": "<MYKEY>"
    },
    "summary": "Creating From Collection",
    "description": {
      "type": "doc",
      "version": 1,
      "content": [
        {
          "type": "paragraph",
          "content": [
            {
              "type": "text",
              "text": "This is an autogenerated issue from a demo."
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "issuetype": {
      "name": "Task"
    }
  }

}

response = requests.post(
    url,
    headers=headers,
    json=json_data,
    verify=False,
    auth=(user, password),
)
```

I get error code 405 and the following message when running print(response.text):


<!doctype html>HTTP Status 405 – Method Not Allowedbody {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;} h1, h2, h3, b {color:white;background-color:#525D76;} h1 {font-size:22px;} h2 {font-size:16px;} h3 {font-size:14px;} p {font-size:12px;} a {color:black;} .line {height:1px;background-color:#525D76;border:none;}

## HTTP Status 405 – Method Not Allowed

**Type** Status Report

**Message** HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL

**Description** The method received in the request-line is known by the origin server but not supported by the target resource.

#### Apache Tomcat/8.5.78

Im sure I'm doing something wrong so any help will be appreciated.

Also I have verified I have the right access by manually going to the project and creating an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your URL is wrong. For creating a Jira issue you want to use the `create issue` endpoint.

[For server/datacenter](https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/9.6.0/#api/2/issue-createIssue):

`url = 'https://<enterprise>jira.<domain>.com/rest/api/2/issue'`

[For cloud](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/api-group-issues/#api-rest-api-3-issue-post):

`url = 'https://<enterprise>jira.<domain>.com/rest/api/3/issue'`

You need to use a POST request to either of these endpoints.

Comment: Thank you this helped solve my issue, I knew something was wrong with the URL I dont know where i got 3 from instead of 2

Comment: 3 is for cloud - so it can be easy to get confused with the documentation sometimes :)